# How to save gif's layers as separate files in GIMP 2.8.16?

Tags: gimp, gif

I tried to google but what it tells is no longer adequate. There are no Export Layers option in menu file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Export Layers now exists as a plugin from [here](http://registry.gimp.org/node/28268)

[image]

Comment: link is a 404 now.  Here is a different link to the plugin I found: https://github.com/khalim19/gimp-plugin-export-layers/releases/download/2.4/export-layers-2.4.zip

Answer (score 1):

Also, with far more functionality, you will probably like the GIMP Animation Package: a plug-in collection that not only is able to "expand" the frames of an animated GIF to a series of images, but offers a lot of functionality to apply filters and other operations on each frame on the expanded video.

Since it depends on volunteer work, you will find GIMP-GAP to be out of date and undermaintained, but if you can manage to get it running at all on your setup, you will be able to do a whole lot of things.
(Windows installers for GIMP 2.8 will have to be hunted around on the internet, but on Linux it usually compiles from source and it is readly available for the major distributions)
http://registry.gimp.org/node/27483

Answer (score 1):

Plug-ins apart, I've answered how to do that by typing a few lines on the Python console that comes pre-installed with GIMP.

There are tutorials around (and other answers of mine) on how to change that into a simple plug-in - the advantage of doing this "manual process" is that you can easily perform other operations on each layer, if you want, as well:

https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/50896/gimp-export-layer-mask-as-png/50951#50951